# How to set up a composer autoloader for modules?

Tags: composer-php

I have some config for project

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Module\\": [
        "app/modules",
        "system/modules"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and classes are available on this path

app/modules/ModuleName/SomeClass.php

How can I make the composer look to

app/modules/ModuleName **/src**/SomeClass.php,

but with old namespace Module\ModuleName?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a corresponding mapping:

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Module\\": [
        "app/modules",
        "system/modules"
      ],
      "Module\\ModuleName\\": [
        "src/"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Mapping `Module\ModuleName` to `app/modules/ModuleName/` is already covered with the existing mapping.